# Open Webpage when sprite clicked

Tags: c#, android, url, unity-game-engine, unityscript

This is what i tried :

```
  Application.OpenURL("http://gameone.co/");
```

But this opens a million of http://gameone.co/ ...
I want to this url open when clicked on a sprite named http. It has also tag of http. But i can delete tag or whatever i want cause it does nothing. And also my project is for Android Build. Can i use raycast on it if hit open url but just 1 time.

More Detail:
i made a 2d game hwo just contain ongui function i have added facebook sdk, google ads sdk, i have installed all the android sdk from sdk manager, i have installed admob plugin vntis. but i havent used facebook sdk. and my pc is 64 bit.

Comment: What do you mean a million of http://gameone.co/. My Turkish friend :)

Comment: 3 bin tane sekme açıyo :D

Comment: tüh bu ne şans sitem çöktü ne olduğunu anlamadan !!! godaddy berbat ya

Comment: did you add this line in the update() method? then it'll open a new page every frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnGUI` function is called many many times in a second. If you add `Application.OpenURL("http://gameone.co/");` into that, the webpage will open as many times.

What you can do is to add [GUI.Button](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html) to the OnGUI function.

```
void OnGUI() {
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 70, 50, 30), "Open webpage!")){
        Application.OpenURL("http://gameone.co/");
    }
}
```

Then the webpage will open only when the button is pressed.

Comment: Yes, there any many ways to do that. For example, if you follow the link there is also GUI.Button that takes `Texture image` as second argument. Or you can add collider to your sprite and raycast based on click/touch, but the code is much more complicated.